# How to capture voice commands when using Google Assistant?

Tags: java, android, voice-recognition, google-assistant-sdk, google-assistant

When a voice command is sent in an application that uses Google Assistant, I want to capture this command and send it to firebase.
How can i do this on android studio using java.
Help will be appericiated.

Comment: Is it your application that handles the voice command or do you want to capture voice commands of other applications?

Comment: It is my application